# Getting all scripts from a users via Javascript

Tags: javascript

so I am trying to get ALL  tags from any user that goes on my site via JS. ATM I have:

```
var scripts = document.scripts.text; // I also tried without the ".text"
let data = {checkout_id: scripts};
```

This weirdly returns NONE of the Javascript I see on inspect element, instead, I get

```
"{'0': {}, '1': {}, '2': {}, '3': {}, '4': {}, '5': {}, '6': {}, '7': {}, '8': {}, '9': {}, '10': {}, '11': {}, 
'12': {}, '13': {}, '14': {}, '15': {}, '16': {}, '17': {}, '18': {}, '19': {}, '20': {}, '21': {}, '22': {}, '23': {}, 
'24': {'timeout': 120}, '25': {'timeout': 120}, '26': {}, '27': {}, '28': {}, 
'29': {}, '30': {}, '31': {}, '32': {}, '33': {}, '34': {}, '35': {}, '36': {}, 
'37': {}, '38': {}, '39': {}, '40': {}, '41': {}, '42': {}, '43': {}, '44': {}, '45': {}, '46': {}, '47': {}, '48': {}, '49': {}, '50': {}}}"
```

What I am expecting to get (or at least one of the scripts is the screenshots below), the highlighted term is my end goal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`document.scripts` is HTML collection, not an array, so first you need to convert it to array (which can be achieved by the spread operator `[...arr]`).

Then you need to display the `outerHTML` to see the scripts.
I hope that this is what you wanted:

```js
let scripts = document.scripts;
let scriptsArray = [...scripts].map(script => script.outerHTML);

console.log(scriptsArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop these elements to retrieve content since it's not array, but [HtmlCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

```js
var collection = document.scripts;
var content = [];

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    content.push(collection.item(i).innerText);
}

console.log(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.scripts` retorna um array na verdade (não exatamente um Array, mas uma lista)

entao, voce tem que iterar sobre esta lista para obter todos os textos

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function() {
        var scripts = document.scripts; // I also tried without the ".text"
        texts = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
          var script = scripts[i];
          texts.push(script.text);
        }

        let data = {checkout_id: texts.join("\n")};
        console.info(data);
      })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```